# Zimbra desktop as default email and calendar application

Tags: 11.10, unity, email

I am reading and looking after this for some time without an answer. I would like to define Zimbra Desktop as my default e-mail and calendar and contact application in ubuntu 11.10, how can i do it?

Thanks.
LF

Comment: This question appears to be abandoned and unanswered, could you perhaps add more detail to your question? If this question no longer applies then you can either delete it or answer it yourself if you've solved the problem. Thanks!